# Unable to update due to less space on boot

Tags: linux, boot, apt, disk-image

I have some old linux images taking up space in /boot

```
$ dpkg -l | grep linux-image
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-70-generic               5.4.0-70.78~18.04.1                              amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.4.0-71-generic               5.4.0-71.79~18.04.1                              amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.4.0-72-generic               5.4.0-72.80~18.04.1                              amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.4.0-73-generic               5.4.0-73.82~18.04.1                              amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.4.0-74-generic               5.4.0-74.83~18.04.1                              amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.4.0-77-generic               5.4.0-77.86~18.04.1                              amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.4.0-80-generic               5.4.0-80.90~18.04.1                              amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.4.0-81-generic               5.4.0-81.91~18.04.1                              amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.4.0-84-generic               5.4.0-84.94~18.04.1                              amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.4.0-86-generic               5.4.0-86.97~18.04.1                              amd64        Signed kernel image generic
iF  linux-image-5.4.0-87-generic               5.4.0-87.98~18.04.1                              amd64        Signed kernel image generic
iF  linux-image-5.4.0-89-generic               5.4.0-89.100~18.04.1                             amd64        Signed kernel image generic
iU  linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04              5.4.0.90.101~18.04.80                            amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

And I am using  **5.4.0-86-generic**

```
 $ uname -r
5.4.0-86-generic
```

And I tried clearing the old linux images using `sudo apt-get purge linux-image-5.4.0-{70,71,72,73,74,77,80}-generic`
then I faced error:

```
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Then tried  `sudo apt --fix-broken install` , but faced the error:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-5.4.0-90-generic_5.4.0-90.101~18.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-90-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-90-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
```

How can I clear space on /boot.

Answer (score 1):

That's a case where using a lower level tool can help instead of causing problems. Usually today it's not a good idea to use `dpkg` directly, but in this case this will help for the same reason: `dpkg` won't check as much as `apt`.

You know you won't use earlier kernel versions installed so you can remove them directly. Assuming a `bash` shell remove all earlier:

```
dpkg --purge linux-image-5.4.0-{70,71,72,73,74,77,80,81,84}-generic
```

Then still have `apt` fix what's broken. As there's now space available, it should succeed in creating one or more *initramfs* files to finish the package(s) installation.

```
apt --fix-broken install
```

Now check again what's left to do:

```
dpkg -l 'linux-image-5.4.*generic' 'linux-image-generic*'
```

If there are still package in bad state (the 2nd column letter is in upper-case, as described in `dpkg`'s output: `Err: uppercase=bad`), which should probably not happen if `/boot` was in a separate partition, reinstall them by using `--fix-broken` and providing a solution. Eg if all last three are still broken:

```
apt-get --fix-broken reinstall linux-image-5.4.0-87-generic linux-image-5.4.0-89-generic linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04
```

(and then probably get rid of `linux-image-5.4.0-87-generic`).

---

Actually using only `apt` or `apt-get` should be doable too but the provided solution must be complete and one must hope deinstallation happens first to free disk space. Probably this would also work (notice the minus sign at the end of the package names from bash expansion, telling `apt` to deinstall instead of reinstall):

```
apt-get --fix-broken --purge reinstall linux-image-5.4.0-{70,71,72,73,74,77,80,81,84}-generic- linux-image-5.4.0-87-generic linux-image-5.4.0-89-generic linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04
```